# "Property is not defined" runtime error in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having an issue using .Net/EF Core, a select statement in one of my view model constructors is returning the following error at **Runtime**: `Property 'System.String Name' is not defined for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer'`.

I've tried commenting out the line I suspected was causing the issue and have narrowed it down to that, but I can't figure out what's wrong with what I'm doing.

The following is the expression that's causing the error:

```
playerholder = players.Select(m => new PlayerListItem_PDMI
            {
                PlayerID = m.PlayerID,
                FirstName = m.FirstName,
                LastName = m.LastName,
                Rating = m.Rating,
                Assigned = m.TeamAssignments.Where(n => n.Team.League == league && n.SeasonID == SeasonID).Count() > 0,
                TeamName = (m.TeamAssignments.Where(n => n.Team.League == league && n.SeasonID == SeasonID).Count() > 0 ? m.TeamAssignments.Where(n => n.Team.League == league && n.SeasonID == SeasonID).First().Team.Name : "Not Assigned")
            }).ToList();
```

and the specific line is

```
TeamName = (m.TeamAssignments.Where(n => n.Team.League == league && n.SeasonID == SeasonID).Count() > 0 ? m.TeamAssignments.Where(n => n.Team.League == league && n.SeasonID == SeasonID).First().Team.Name : "Not Assigned")
```

What am I missing here?

**Note:** The database being queried is completely empty. The check for records should return false and make the ternary expression return "Not Assigned"

Edit:

The **TeamAssignment** class is as follows:

```
public class TeamAssignment : IModel
{
    public TeamAssignment()
    {

    }

    public TeamAssignment(WWAHLContext db)
    {
        Season = db.Seasons.Last();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int PlayerID { get; set; }

    public int SeasonID { get; set; }

    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    public int PlayerNumber { get; set; }

    public Position Position { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PlayerID")]
    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamID")]
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SeasonID")]
    public virtual Season Season { get; set; }
}
```

and the **Team** class is this:

```
public class Team : IModel
{
    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    public int SeasonID { get; set; }

    public League League { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual TeamStats TeamStats { get; set; }

    public virtual TeamCarousel Carousel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GameDetails> Games { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CurrentTeam> CurrentPlayers { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Penalty> Penalties => Games.SelectMany(m => m.Penalties);
}
```

Comment: Show Team class please

Comment: Is this a run-time error ?

Comment: @user3185569 Yes, it is.

Comment: Why don't you show the `CurrentTeam` class also ?

Comment: I renamed it to TeamAssignment because I realised CurrentTeam didn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Why don't you just use a Left Join instead of this complicated query ?

Comment: @user3185569 Because the query wasn't complicated until I needed to add the last line :p (To clarify, I'm working on restructuring it, although I am still curious why this way doesn't work)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by using joins as follows (edited for left outer join):

```
playerholder = players.GroupJoin(db.TeamAssignments, player => player.PlayerID, assignment => assignment.PlayerID, (player, assignment) => new
        {
            PlayerID = player.PlayerID,
            FirstName = player.FirstName,
            LastName = player.LastName,
            Rating = player.Rating,
            NameLeague = assignment.Where(m => m.SeasonID == seasonId).Join(db.Teams, assign => assign.TeamID, team => team.TeamID, (assign, team) => new
            {
                League = team.League,
                Name = team.Name
            }).Where(m => m.League == league)
        }).Select(m => new PlayerListItem_PDMI
        {
            PlayerID = m.PlayerID,
            FirstName = m.FirstName,
            LastName = m.LastName,
            Rating = m.Rating,
            Assigned = m.NameLeague.Any(),
            TeamName = (m.NameLeague.Any() ? m.NameLeague.First().Name : "Not Assigned")
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make a sensible query out of this.....

```
playerholder = from m in players
           let team = m.TeamAssignments.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Team.League == league && n.SeasonID == SeasonID)
           select new PlayerListItem_PDMI
           {
            PlayerID = m.PlayerID,
            FirstName = m.FirstName,
            LastName = m.LastName,
            Rating = m.Rating,
            Assigned = team != null,
            TeamName = team != null ? team.Name : "Not Assigned")
        }).ToList();
```

Just try that first to see if it works, or gives the same error.   Since the error references `ValueBuffer`, I'm going to guess that the thing `.Name` is attached to is not a `Team` object --- possibility due to a misplace parenthesis in that mess...